# Finding unique items in list and add them to new list with list comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given `myList1`

```
myList1 = [5,3,7,2,88,42,2,4,3,7,2]
```

I like to add all items off my `myList1` to `myList2` but each unique item only once.
So I am expecting a list like this:

```
[5, 3, 7, 2, 88, 42, 4]
```

I want to do this with list comprehension. I tried this but it gives me again the same items as in `myList1`

```
myList2 = []
myList2 = [item for item in myList1 if item not in myList2]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `list2 = sorted(list(set(myList1)),key=myList1.index)` is likely a better way of doing it imho ... but if you do it with a list comprehension there is not a very clean way to do it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First assuming you care about maintaining order:** here's the way I tend to do it if I'm using a list-comp:

```
seen = set()
myList2 = [x for x in myList1 if x not in seen and not seen.add(x)]
```

Or alternately

```
from collections import OrderedDict
myList2 = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(myList1))
```

Both of these approaches are O(n).  You have to be careful when doing this operation not to make your algorithm O(n**2) by doing repeated membership tests (or `index` searches) against a `list`.

If you *don't* care about order, you really just want to just do:

```
mySet = set(myList1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are seeing all the elements in the list is because `myList2` is only being set to the new list(created by the comprehension) after the comprehension is completed. That means that within the list comprehension it always sees `myList2` as an empty list so every item is not in the list therefore it puts it in the new list.

You could accomplish that very easily if you use a `set`.

```
myList1 = [5,3,7,2,88,42,2,4,3,7,2]


s = list(set(myList1))

print s
```

Comment: unless he wants the same order as the list... in which case he will need to sort it

Comment: sure if that's a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you REALLY want to use a list comprehension, and you don't want to use a `set` as suggested:

```
[myList1[i] for i in range(len(myList1)) if not myList1[i] in myList1[:i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Many good suggestions on how to do it right. A brief explanation of *why* your code doesn't work may be helpful here. In `myList2 = [item for item in myList1 if item not in myList2]`, `if item not in myList2` one get evaluated once in the beginning of the loop when `myList2` is empty. In the following example, `if item not in myList2` will be in every loop during which a new value is also appended to `myList2`:

```
>>> myList1 = [5,3,7,2,88,42,2,4,3,7,2]
>>> myList2 = []
>>> for item in myList1:
    if item not in myList2:
        myList2.append(item)        
>>> myList2
[5, 3, 7, 2, 88, 42, 4]
```

And we get the intended result.